# How can I return to a parent activity correctly from Search activity which is launched from ActionBar SearchView.

Tags: android, search, android-activity, android-actionbar, parent

I have Two Activities `MainActivity` And `SearchActivity`. The `SearchActivity` is Launched From `ActionBar` Search `View` Menu Item. but if i Come back to the `MainActivity` by clicking  Up Navigation Item the `MainActivity` state is lost how can i go back to Main Activity with out losing the state of `MainActivity` .

**My Code: MainActivity**

```
   @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerLinear );
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);


        SearchItem= menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
         SearchView searchView =
                 (SearchView) SearchItem.getActionView();

         searchView.setQueryRefinementEnabled(true);
         searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
         searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                 searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
  return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

**My Code: SearchActivity**

```
  @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
  default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
```

How can i return from SearchActivity to MainActivity with out Recreating the MainActivity.

Answer (score 1):

You can change activity launch mode for MainActivity to single top when you back from SearchActivity . This will not recreate the activity. Check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)  for more info

```
 @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
               startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class)
                                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)//updated
                                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
                            );
                        }
                    });
                return true;
                default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Still the mainactivity is refreshing.